# Is there a function that replaces a product by convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

Consider two functions $f(x),g(x) = 0 \forall x<0$, I'd like to know if we can always find an $h(x)$ which satisfies the integral equation $$f(x)g(x) = h(x)*f(x)$$ where '$*$' is the convolution operator.

Comment: are you looking for the Fourier transform?

Comment: @JanDvorak : No, I am interested in a function, not transform. I know Fourier transform converts product into convolution, but thats not what I want.

Comment: Well, then there's $h(x) = 0$, but I guess you're not looking for that either.  I'm afraid there's no function that satisfies your needs.

Comment: @JanDvorak : How does $h(x) = 0$ satisfy? looks like there is some misterpretation.

Comment: Hmm... I thought you mistyped your second formula and you meant $ h(f(x)g(x)) = h(f(x))*g(f(x))$; I don't think there's any possible $h(x)$ in any case.

Comment: For one, $g(x)$ appears nowhere on the RHS of that formula, meaning that $h$ should be dependent on $g$.

Comment: @JanDvorak : yes $h(x)$ is dependent on $g(x)$.

Comment: Then, do you allow dependency of $h$ on $f$ as well?

Comment: @JanDvorak : No ofcourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is *no* except for some trivial cases such as $g(x) \equiv 0$. The equation on the left depends only on instantaneous value of $f$ while the one on the right depends on all the values of $f$. There is no way the two can be equal as an identity.

More to the point you want

$$f(x) g(x) = \int_0^{\infty} f(\tau) h(x-\tau) d \tau$$

Even if you make $h$ causal, the right hand side will still depend on $f(\tau), 0\le \tau \le x$ but the left hand side depends only on $f(x)$